# Why does US jobs and inflation have an affect on European equities?

Tags: inflation, stock-market

There are articles such as 'European shares crawl higher as investors eye US inflation data'. Is this just put down to Americans may have more money to spend overseas so investors speculate higher earnings or is there another relationship?

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-europe-stocks/u-s-jobs-report-boosts-european-stocks-idUSKCN1GL0ZU

Edit: Added article link for clarification.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Economics.SE! can you be more specific as to which articles you are referring to?

Comment: @EconJohn Thanks John, this an exmaple of an article https://www.reuters.com/article/us-europe-stocks/u-s-jobs-report-boosts-european-stocks-idUSKCN1GL0ZU